# Is Python's gzip.writer known to be slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compression, gzip

I've written a script to process CSV files for my employer. The processing is CPU-bound and the files are large. For example, a 3+ GB of input yields 6+ GB of output.

On my machine the transformation of that text-file takes almost 16 minutes (which itself is kinda long, but I'm using the stock `csv`-module), about 30 seconds of which is spent by the OS (writing the output).

For kicks, I added a feature of transparent compression:

```
if name.endswith('.gz'):
    import gzip
    return gzip.GzipFile(name, mode, 9, fd)
return fd
```

When using compression, the run time jumps to over an hour -- although the sys-time halves, because there is a lot less to write.

The jump is understandable, but the scale of it is not -- if I simply run `gzip -9` on the uncompressed output file, it takes only about 13 minutes.

I can understand, that `gzip` may win *something* by using bigger buffers, etc. -- but embedding compression in my script should be able to benefit from less data-copying. And yet, it loses worse than 2:1: 16 minutes to transform + 13 minutes to compress vs. 61 minutes to do both in one go.

Why is there such a large discrepancy? Is the zlib/gzip code in Python-2.x known to be slow? Should Python-3 be better in this regard -- it is significantly worse in uncompressed processing...

Comment: Yes that's slow because of `GIL` https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: What's your OS ?

Comment: I tried on both FreeBSD and Linux -- the timing discrepancies are comparable on both operating systems. I don't see, what [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) has to do with it, though -- nothing in my code is multi-threaded, it processes one file at a time.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.8 and I still suspect that Python's gzipping is slow...

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine noticed that the default compression level between Python's gzip and bash's gzip are different.

[Python's implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) uses a compression level of 9 (the slowest) by default

> `gzip.open(filename, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)`

The [bash gzip command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) uses level 6 by default:

> The default compression level is -6 (that is, biased towards high compression at expense of speed).

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that you actually _account_ for compression levels in your question. So maybe this isn't the source of the problem...

Comment: ... and there is no such thing as "bash gzip command" either :-)